# Datatable + ajax rowSelect + primefaces

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, datatable

Estou fazendo um projeto JSF com Primefaces e tenho uma datatable que carrega meu model, até aí tudo ok. Fiz um método ajax com rowSelect, para
ao clicar na linha direcionar para outra página e passar o objeto via select event, o problema é que apesar desse método estar chamando o bean corretamente ele está sendo acionado
toda vez que a datatable é carregada, então sempre tenho o primeiro registro da tabela e não a linha clicada.

- O escopo do bean é @SessionScoped (Se mudar para @ViewScoped ou @RequestScoped nem carrega os dados e mesmo assim chama o método)
- O bean da datatable e da página de destino são diferentes, mas já tentei colocar no mesmo e continua do mesmo jeito.

Segue os códigos:
1- Código do xhtml

```
    <div style="min-height: 400px">
    <p:dataTable value="#{equipamentoMB.listEquipamentos}" var="eqto"
        id="tabelaEquipamento" lazy="false" paginator="true"
        paginatorPosition="bottom" rows="25" selectionMode="single"
        selection="#{editaEquipamentoMB.equipamentoSelecionado}"
        rowKey="#{editaEquipamentoMB.equipamentoSelecionado.id}"
        rendered="#{equipamentoMB.viewDataTable}">
        <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{editaEquipamentoMB.onSelectRow}"
            process="@this" oncomplete="self.location= 'edit_equipamento.xhtml';" />
```

2- Código do bean:

```
    public void onSelectRow(SelectEvent<EquipamentoDTO> event) {

    if (event.getObject() != null) {
        
        equipamentoSelecionado = new EquipamentoDTO(event.getObject());
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Resolvido, o problema era a rowKey que estava apontando para o bean.id e não para var.id, o código ficou assim:

```
    <div style="min-height: 400px">
<p:dataTable value="#{equipamentoMB.listEquipamentos}" var="eqto"
    id="tabelaEquipamento" lazy="false" paginator="true"
    paginatorPosition="bottom" rows="25" selectionMode="single"
    selection="#{editaEquipamentoMB.equipamentoSelecionado}"
    rowKey="#{eqto.id}"
    rendered="#{equipamentoMB.viewDataTable}">
    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{editaEquipamentoMB.onSelectRow}"
        process="@this" oncomplete="self.location= 'edit_equipamento.xhtml';" />
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).